# Python Dataframe to List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking to convert my dataframe into the following format but am getting confused on the format of the dictionaries. How would I do this?

```
df.headers() = ['Date','Label','Category']
```

Desired format

```
fig['layout']['annotations'] = [dict(x=df['Date'],y=df['Label'],text=df['Label']),
                                    dict(x=df['Date'],y=df['Label'],text=df['Label']...)]
```

Sample

```
fig['layout']['annotations'] = [dict(x='2022-12-07 00:00:00',y=63,text="This is a label"),
                                    dict(x='2021-11-01 00:00:00',y=15,text="Testing")]
```

[image]

Comment: Please show how you are importing data into dataframe and what your dataframe looks like. Why is it Date, Label and Label and not Date Label and Category

Comment: Data comes in from an Excel file and sample data is shown above. This is going into a gantt chart (there is more data not shown) so the Label will both be the Y-Axis label and the label on the bar itself